# how to resolve two POST methods in one controller

Tags: java, rest, post

I am using REST api and have following methods in my user controller

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User login(UserLogin userLogin){
```

and other method is

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean register(User user){
```

I want to call login method on login button click and pretty obviously register method on register button click. UserLogin class has only two attibs (email and password). User has meany fileds like name, address, contact etc

my REST call `http://localhost:8080/... / ... /user` routes properly to login method on login button click but it again calls the same method on register click and throws an exception that fields like name etc are undefined for UserLogin class.

Why are thee two clicks getting routed to same method?
How to resolve this?

Comment: You can't without different paths. How do you expect the application to determine which one to pick? Off the method parameter? That's not gonna work. If you really want to make it work, you can hack it, but it would look so ugly, I wouldn't even recommend it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add @Path annotation to define a unique path for each method.

for example:

```
@Path("/register")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public boolean register(User user){
```

then call your method with `http://localhost:8080/... / ... /user/register`.